# Google Sheets formula every x rows, assign incrementing cell value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Sheet, with the first row container headers (so row references will be -1) and rows are "grouped" by every 7 rows. See below.

[image: Example Google Sheet]

I've manually typed the numbers into the `Image #` column, but is there a way to use a formula to enter in an incrementing number every 7 rows into that column so I don't have to it for 80+ unique `Caption`s? I'm doing this to keep track of how many unique `Caption` rows there are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try, `1` in A2 and in A3 copied down:

```
=if(mod(row(),7)=2,A2+1,A2)
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked like a charm. Thanks!